# Redirect from non-www to www site in .htaccess in proper way

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to redirect non-www prefix pages to www prefix pages.

However, I have to do this in vanilla forum which already has few redirect rules in htaccess.

I have added the redirect code above it. I would like to know whether this is correct? It is working fine but I feel performance problem as the forum is loading really slow.

---

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /forum
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gtricks.com [NC]
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gtricks.com/forum/$1 [L,R=301]

   # Certain hosts may require the following line.
   # If vanilla is in a subfolder then you need to specify it after the /. 
   # (ex. You put Vanilla in /forum so change the next line to: RewriteBase /forum)
   # RewriteBase /forum
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Can anyone help me telling this is not standard or the better way of doing it.

PS: The forum is not at the root but in folder named 'forum'. At root there is already wordpress blog.

Comment: All looks fine to me. Any slowness you experience while the forum is loading I wouldn't attribute to your `.htaccess` additions. In fact, it seemed reasonably fast for me (<3s).

Comment: Where is this .htaccess file located?

Answer (score 2):

This is my redirect code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Looks the same. I don't think this is the cause of your performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have done is the standard method of redirecting a non www page to its www page at the .htaccess level. There is no other better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need edit htaccess. You can do it more safely by specifying the preferred URL in Settings.

[image]

If you have `domain.com` and want users to be redirected to `www.domain.com` , then keep `www.domain.com` iin the settings and vice versa. Wordpress will manage the www redirection.